# I'm trying to make a batch file that moves files by random

Tags: batch-file

I already have a code, but it keeps selecting the first file on the list and it's getting irritating. I have no idea what to do.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
CD c:\"destination"\somefolder
set n=0
for %%f in (*.*) do (
set /a n+=1
set "file[!n!]=%%f"
)
set /a rand=(n*%random% %%4) /4
move "!file[%rand%]!" C:\destination\somefolder
pause
```

Comment: I posted it! :-) sorry it's a little wonky since I typed it on my phone

Comment: What are you trying to do with `set /a rand=(n*%random% %%4) /4`?

Comment: Well, the original code was 
`set /a "rand=(n*%random%)/32768+1`
But I wanted the batch file to select a random file and move it to the desired location, but all it's doing it sending the first file from list to the folder. And it does it repeatedly. I was doing several examples to figure out what's going on, and that's one of them.

Comment: Please look on `set /a rand=(n*%random% %%4) /4` and think about this arithmetic expression. Let's say `n = 19` and `random = 37` then the expression is `19 * 37 = 703 % 4 = 3 / 4 = 0`. The remainder of any `value % 4` is always in range `0` to `3`. The result of a value in range `0` to `3` divided by `4` is always `0`. So your modification on arithmetic expression is not good, isn't it.

Comment: The help output on running in a command prompt window `set /?` outputs on last page `%RANDOM% - expands to a random decimal number between 0 and 32767.` Now look on original `set /a rand=(n*%random%)/32768+1` and you see this arithmetic expression really selects randomly a number in range `1` to `n`.

Answer (score 1):

rand with 30bit size(value from 0 to 2^30-1 modulo n)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
pushd c:\"source"\somefolder
set "n=0"
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b /a-d *.*') do (
  rem number files from 0 and use full filename with spaceses
  set "file[!n!]=%%~ff"
  set /a "n+=1"
)
popd
if  %n% leq  32768 ( set /a "rand=%random%%%n%"
) else set /a "rand=((%random%<<15)+%random%)%%n%"
move "!file[%rand%]!" C:\destination\somefolder
pause
endlocal
```